# intercepting $resource and $http responses angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json response:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "error": "Server says no.",
  "data": []
}
```

wrapped in `$resource` like this:

```
$resource("path-to-file.json", null, {
  query: {
    method: "GET",
    isArray: false,
    responseType: "json",
    interceptor: {
      response: function (response) {
        if (!response.data.success) {
          // stop propagation of events/promises and trigger error
        }
        // do something else with response.data
        return response;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

If `"success": false` I want to trigger the error function of `$http`.

I want to do this:

```
$scope.myVar = MyService.query(); // MyService returns $resource
```

in a controller. The response gets passed to `$scope.myVar` regardless of what I try and do.

Comment: Maybe pointing out the obvious, but you're aware of the typo in "inteceptor" right? It should be "interceptor".

Comment: @J.P.tenBerge thanks. Spelling corrected. That's not the issue unfortunately. I got the spelling correct in my actual app!

Comment: In addition to Chandermani's answer, shouldn't you check `response.success` instead of `response.data.success`?

Comment: No. `response` is `{data: Object, status: 200, headers: function, config: Object, resource: Resource}`. The contents of the JSON is the data object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth remembering that:

> The ngResource module provides interaction support with RESTful services [1](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource)

When they say "RESTful services" they mean that they're making some assumptions about how your endpoint is going to behave. One of these assumptions is that the success or error status is going to be encoded by the HTTP Status Code.

It sounds like you're trying to interact with a service that doesn't fit this pattern (i.e. you can have a failed request that returns `200: OK`). If that's the case you'd probably better off using `$http` directly, since it is more general:

> The $http service is a core Angular service that facilitates communication with the remote HTTP servers [2](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http)

Since `$resource` is really just a wrapper around `$http` we can confirm the behaviour fairly easily by having a look at [the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L461) (edited for clarity):

```
var promise = $http(httpConfig).then(function(response) {
  var data = response.data,
      promise = value.$promise;

  // snip

  value.$resolved = true;

  response.resource = value;

  return response;
}, function(response) {
  value.$resolved = true;

  (error||noop)(response);

  return $q.reject(response);
});

promise = promise.then(
    function(response) {
      var value = responseInterceptor(response);
      (success||noop)(value, response.headers);
      return value;
    },
    responseErrorInterceptor);
```

Remember that `then()` takes a success and an error callback in that order. You can see that your interceptor is going to get called on success, along with the main success callback if there is one.

It doesn't look like there's anything you can do inside your `responseInterceptor` that will cause the error callback to be executed.

I think your options are:

- Modify the your server to behave in the way that `$resource` expects
- Roll your own version of `$resource` built on top of `$http` that works the way you want it to as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12805450/1344760).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (!response.data.success) {
          return $q.reject(rejection);
 }
```

See if this call the error callback. I got it from the documentation of `$http` http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Comment: I tried/saw that. Unfortunately it doesn't work. reject[ing] in response doesn't trigger responseError (or appear to do anything). The only way I've found to trigger responseError is via a HTTP response code.